# Benefits of non-tracking pixel to https to prewarm SSL handshake from http page

Tags: performance, optimization, https

A client has an e-commerce website with the homepage, listing and detail pages (i.e. the catalog) over standard non-secure HTTP. The sign-in, cart, and checkout pages are behind secure https on the same domain. This is due to be changed later in the year, I'm well aware of how far behind the times http is but it is in the works.

However as an immediate optimization, quick to apply, is there any benefit to including a 1px x 1px img pixel pointing to a https img on the http page catalog pages?

Would this in any way prewarm the SSL handshake for when the end user adds an item to cart resulting in faster acknowledgement (cart is non-ajax again to be changed). I'm thinking about caching of certificate validation, revocation list checking etc..

Is there any downsides to this?

Answer (score 2):

No downside compared to no pixel.

Downsides compare to a full-https website:

- Slower (except if all resources of the http pages use https, which will made de pixel useless)
- Less secure (vulnerable to sslstrip attacks, can't use HSTS)